# Jquery plugin tools for maps

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

Can anyone suggest a link or an example to create an atlas like tool using jquery

What does google maps use?

Thanks..

Comment: I think you have to be more specific about what the "atlas like tool" is supposed to do exactly.

Comment: @ Pekka:I wanted a tool in which a map would be scrollable just like google maps and can locate various country name ,states etc..

Comment: Google maps uses...well, google maps, that's completely by the google guys, not built on any framework like jQuery.

Comment: Try http://www.maplib.net/ ... it's a service, not a plugin though. It also uses Google's Map API.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:**

there is no jQuery plugin for make a plug & play application map like google maps!

you must built your own and this not a simple task! and in any case is not a thing that can be done by a one man show!

so if you are planning to do this for a little map area, you can do this as easy explaned in this tut

> - http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/page/a-jquery-plugin-for-zoomable-interactive-maps
> - http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/mapbox/

but of course you can make it have a better look and usability by using what i have provided to you below!

otherwise you must use flash or just google maps!

---

if you want use jquery!

you definitely need this plugin for **move the map**:

> - http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

plus you need to have a good knowledge of **CSS position** properties

> - http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp
> - http://www.positioniseverything.net/

and practical **tutorials**

> - http://designreviver.com/tutorials/css-image-map-techniques-and-tutorials/

and maybe usefull for you have some knowledge of **area** tag

> - http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_area.asp

try also this usefull **image mapping tool**

> - http://www.image-maps.com/
> - http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap

hope this is a good starting point for you! ;-)

Comment: when one downvote, is supposed to have a good reason, i can't see any good reason here!